# How do I export iPhone contacts to Excel or CSV file?

Tags: iphone, contacts

Not only would I like to backup my contacts to an external storage drive so I can use it for a mail merge.

How can I export iOS contacts to a spreadsheet?

Comment: You can't. Not without a Mac AFAIK.

Comment: @IronCraftMan, You said, "_You can't. Not without a Mac AFAIK_, okay, you did say "AFAIK" however, not counting the app mention in bret7600's answer (and there are others too for the iPhone), what about syncing with iTunes on Windows and then exporting to CSV from whatever app iTunes syncs the Contacts in Windows with. Pebbles-the-Cat only mentioned iPhone as the device, didn't say which or other computer might be involved.

Comment: idk whether this would be any good to you, even as an intermediate step, but you can download any/all contacts as vCard directly from your iCloud web page

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution if you have the Numbers app:

- Open the Contacts app
- Select all contacts using Command-A
- Drag & drop the contacts on the Numbers app
- Using the Numbers app, you can export your contacts to CSV or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get your CSV file. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8

You can backup 500 before you have to spend a few bucks.